# Another - Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

Tags: json, typescript, stringify

I have a json string created by

```
let jsonString = "{ \"AjaxBookGenieParams\": " + JSON.stringify(ajaxBookGenieParams) + " }";
```

I have a problem with a web service call not liking the string. I get:

> 500 Internal Server Server Error - missing value for parameter: ajaxBookGenieParams.

When I use JSONLint it gives me the error:

> Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

Where might I have gone wrong?
Thanks
Abbott

```
{ \"AjaxBookGenieParams\":{
  \"AgeCandidates\":[],
  \"AgeItemToDelete\":{ 
    \"ISBN\":\"\",
    \"ProductId\":0,
    \"ImageUrl\":\"\",
    \"Title\":\"\",
    \"Price\":0,
    \"Quantity\":0,
    \"AgeId\":0},
    \"AllocatedBooks\":[]},
\"BookGenieParams\":{
    \"AllocatedQuantity\":0,
    \"AllocatedSubTotal\":0,
    \"AllocatedTitles\":0,
    \"AllocationBudget\":200,
    \"BooksPerTitle\":5,
    \"CustomerGuid\":\"\",
    \"CustomerId\":0,
    \"DefaultBooksPerTitle\":5,
    \"MinimumBudget\":200,
    \"MoveToCartSubTotal\":0,
    \"MoveToCartCount\":0,
    \"ReDisplayBreak\":10,
    \"SelectedCategories\":[],
    \"UserBooksPerTitle\":0},
\"Data\":\"\",
\"ProductFilterParams\":{
    \"RootNodes\":[
        {\"Id\":50,
        \"Name\":\"Ages\",
        \"GroupType\":\"ages\",
        \"NodeCategories\":[
            {\"Id\":38,\"Name\":\"Ages 0 to 2\",\"Count\":54,\"Selected\":\"off\",\"Description\":\"\",\"GroupCats\":[]},
            {\"Id\":34,\"Name\":\"Ages 3 to 5\",\"Count\":536,\"Selected\":\"off\",\"Description\":\"\",\"GroupCats\":[]},
            {\"Id\":35,\"Name\":\"Ages 6 to 8\",\"Count\":471,\"Selected\":\"off\",\"Description\":\"\",\"GroupCats\":[]},
            {\"Id\":37,\"Name\":\"Ages 9 to 12\",\"Count\":1126,\"Selected\":\"off\",\"Description\":\"\",\"GroupCats\":[]},
            {\"Id\":36,\"Name\":\"Young Adult\",\"Count\":803,\"Selected\":\"off\",\"Description\":\"\",\"GroupCats\":[]}],
        \"Description\":\"Books By Age\",
        \"ToolTip\":\"\",
        \"Selected\":\"off\",
        \"__expanded__\":false}],
    \"FilterGuid\":\"\",
    \"AgeRange\":{\"Min\":1,
    \"Max\":18,\"From\":3,
    \"FromInit\":3,
    \"To\":12,
    \"ToInit\":12},
    \"SelectedAges\":[],
    \"FilterCategories\":{},
    \"ResetFilter\":\"false\"},
\"Request\":\"StartAllocationToCart\"}
```

}

Comment: Can you use an editor which validates the JSON schema as you write it? VS Code or any JetBrains can do it for you.
Why are do you write the JSON schema by hand by the way? Can you serialize it from objects or something?

Comment: maybe upper/lower-case: your error-message says `ajaxBookGenieParams`, but your JSON contains `AjaxBookGenieParams`

Comment: This is what was serialized from my object. ...
let jsonString = "{ \"AjaxBookGenieParams\": " + JSON.stringify(ajaxBookGenieParams)

Comment: I used VS Code to validate the json and was able to mke some changes that made it pass the lint test. Now I have to see wehy my Serialize did not give what I thought it would give me.
Thanks alot.
Abbott

Comment: I went on VS code and cleaned up some formatting. No changes. When I linted it, it passed. I did file compare on the two saved files of the json and they compared as equal content. I'm feeling really stupid here.

Comment: This calling approach & structure works in other parts of my projects.
A note, this is used in TScript, the other in JScript.

static AllocationQuery(url: string, method: string, ajaxBookGenieParams:AjaxBookGenieParams, allowWindowClose : boolean) {
      
        let jsonString = "{ \"AjaxBookGenieParams\": " + JSON.stringify(ajaxBookGenieParams) + " }";
        let myUrl = url + method;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: myUrl,
            data: jsonString,
            contentType: "...",
            dataType: "json",
            async: allowWindowClose,

Answer (score 3):

Why are you building a JSON string by yourself in the first place?

```
const jsonString = JSON.stringify({
    AjaxBookGenieParams: ajaxBookGenieParams,
});
```

Comment: To include in the ajax call

Comment: You’re doing it wrong.

Comment: emix, what am I doing wrong?
Thanks
Abbott

Comment: I've shown you how to create the JSON string properly.

Comment: I'm sorry (I'm an oldster - 77) and I missed that, When I used your format it worked. I'm running solo so I miss a lot of things ... thanks for the patience.

Comment: Never too late to improve in IT, I respect that. Please mark my answer as the solution if I managed to help you. Thanks.

Comment: That solved the problem but did not get me past a WebMethod error about the json. Uggh.